# How to parse a string, which is a list of ints into a list in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

I have a string which is a list of ints, and I need to parse it into a list of those ints. In other words, how to convert `"[2017,7,18,9,0]"` to `[2017,7,18,9,0]`?

#### more info

When i `console.log(typeof [2017,7,18,9,0], [2017,7,18,9,0] )`, I get: `string [2017,7,18,9,0]`. I need to convert it into a list such that doing `console.log()`, i get:  `object Array [ 2017, 7, 18, 9, 0 ]`.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: use `JSON.parse`! `var array = JSON.parse(string);`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `.match()` with `RegExp` `/\d+/`, `.map()` with parameter `Number`

```
var res = "[2017,7,18,9,0]".match(/\d+/g).map(Number)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try parsing it as JSON:

```js
console.log(JSON.parse("[2017,7,18,9,0]"))
```

Or you could try to manually parse the string:

```js
var str = "[2017,7,18,9,0]";
str = str.substring(1, str.length - 1); // cut out the brackets
var list = str.split(",");
console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var yourString = "[2017,7,18,9,0]";
var stringArray = JSON.parse(yourString);
console.log( JSON.stringify(stringArray), typeof stringArray);
```

Is it JSON.parse that you need?

Answer (score 1):

By splitting with regex (*because who doesn't love a regex*):

```
var array = "[2017,7,18,9,0]".split(/\,|\[|\]/).shift().pop();
```

The shift and pop remove the empty strings from the front and back of the array, which are from the open and close brackets.

Comment: You could do the same with `/\D+/`

Comment: @sin thanks, that's cool. And shorter

Answer (score 0):

These solutions are turning into a list of every available option. So in that spirit I'll throw `eval()` into the mix.

```
eval("[2017, 23, 847, 4]");
```

**NOTE:** the other answers are much better and this method should not be used.

```js
var strArray = "[2017, 23, 847, 4]";

var realArray = eval(strArray);

console.log(realArray);
```